# calculate the average of each user in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame (df) with these columns: user, values, and time.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3','user_1', 'user_2',  'user_3',
                            'user_1', 'user_2',  'user_3'],
                   'values': [[1, 0, 2, 0], [1, 8, 0, 2],[6, 2, 0, 0],
                              [5, 0, 2, 2], [3, 8, 0, 0],[6, 0, 0, 2],
                             [3, 1, 1, 3], [2, 4, 1, 0],[4, 2, 0, 1]],
                   'time': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]})
```

output:

```
    user       values     time
0   user_1  [1, 0, 2, 0]    1
1   user_2  [1, 8, 0, 2]    1
2   user_3  [6, 2, 0, 0]    1
3   user_1  [5, 0, 2, 2]    2
4   user_2  [3, 8, 0, 0]    2
5   user_3  [6, 0, 0, 2]    2
6   user_1  [3, 1, 1, 3]    3
7   user_2  [2, 4, 1, 0]    3
8   user_3  [4, 2, 0, 1]    3
```

I would like to calculate the average value of each user with respect to the previous value of time.

For example:

For user_1:-

For time=1 the average is calculated for values of user_1 in time 1= [1, 0, 2, 0]

For time=2, the average is calculated for values of user_1 in time 1 and 2
= [1+5/2, 0+0/2, 2+2/2, 0+2/2]=[3, 0, 2, 1]

For time=3 the average is calculated for values of user_1 in time 2 (which is [3, 0, 2, 1]) and 3 (which is [3, 1, 1, 3])= [3+3/2, 0+1/2, 2+1/2, 1+3/2]=[3, 0.5, 1.5, 2]

and so on for all users.

So, the expected result for user_1 is:

```
in time 1: [1, 0, 2, 0]
in time 2: [3, 0, 2, 1]
in time 3: [3, 0.5, 1.5, 2]
```

I tried the following code which

```
result = (df.groupby('user')['values']
         .agg(lambda x: np.vstack(x).mean(0).round(2))
       )

print(result)
```

result

```
user
user_1    [3.0, 0.33, 1.67, 1.67]
user_2    [2.0, 6.67, 0.33, 0.67]
user_3     [5.33, 1.33, 0.0, 1.0]
```

but it returns the average value for each user with respect to all time! I would like to calculate the average value of each user with respect to current t and previous t-1, like in example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ Simon Lundberg I updated my code

Comment: Try with for loop

Comment: @ BENY could you give an example based on my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with for loop

```
all = []
for x , y in  df.groupby('user'): 
    l = [np.array(y['values'].iloc[0])]
    for z in y['values'].iloc[1:] :
        m = np.array(z)
        l.append((m + l[-1])/2)
    all.append(l)
all
Out[442]: 
[[array([1, 0, 2, 0]), array([3., 0., 2., 1.]), array([3. , 0.5, 1.5, 2. ])],
 [array([1, 8, 0, 2]), array([2., 8., 0., 1.]), array([2. , 6. , 0.5, 0.5])],
 [array([6, 2, 0, 0]), array([6., 1., 0., 1.]), array([5. , 1.5, 0. , 1. ])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) magic:

```
df = df.pivot(index='user', columns='time', values='values').\
    pipe(lambda df: df.explode(df.columns.tolist())).convert_dtypes()\
    .expanding(axis=1).mean().round(2)\
    .reset_index().groupby('user').agg(list)

print(df)
```

The result is a reshaped dataframe organized by `user`/`time` columns and implied `mean` calculations:

```
time                       1                     2                        3
user                                                                       
user_1  [1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0]  [3.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0]  [3.0, 0.33, 1.67, 1.67]
user_2  [1.0, 8.0, 0.0, 2.0]  [2.0, 8.0, 0.0, 1.0]  [2.0, 6.67, 0.33, 0.67]
user_3  [6.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0]  [6.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]   [5.33, 1.33, 0.0, 1.0]
```